# "Top 1 %" or "99th percentile" for formal usage?

Tags: formality

Which is more formal (i.e. on a resume), "top 1%" or "99th percentile." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Top 1%** is fine

Typically one does not use "percentile" unless speaking of a test where the results were reported as percentiles.  To say that you graduated at the top of your class, it's more common to say "in the top 1%.

Comment: I think the 99% was a typo, in fairness the OP did write *99th...* in the question title.

Comment: Also, in strict formality it would be "one percent" rather than "1%".